# What visual studio code formatter can i use to format .hbs handlebars files?

Tags: visual-studio-code, format, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I am working on a *Node.js* project that has **Handlebars** `.hbs` files in it. I am unable to format the `.hbs` files, because the standard version of the **Prettier** extension for **VS Code** doesn't support the `.hbs` file-type, or the *Handlebars syntax*.

##### What visual studio code formatter can i use to format `.hbs` handlebars files?

Comment: if I search the market place there are formatters for handlebar

Comment: I personally use the default "HTML Language Features" as a formatter... It formats the HTML part of the .hbs file. The handlebars code is left untouched, which is a good thing, since there aren't many good hbs file formatters in the market at the moment

Answer (score 4):

##### Try using the extension: "mfeckies.handlebars-formatter"

It worked well for me when I was working with `.hbs` files 18 months ago.